# Rustic way to mutate struct using its attributes outside itself

Tags: rust, mutex

I want to mutate `Outer` struct using itself outside its implementation and without coping its attributes. How to implement it in Rust correctly? Is there a rustic way to have mutable and immutable references in the same time?

Here the code example (maybe this is far-fetched, but it illustrates the problem I face very good):

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Inner {
    n: i64,
    factor: i64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Max {
    v: i64
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Outer {
    inners: Vec<Inner>,
    max: Max,
}

fn main() {
    let mutex_s = Mutex::new(Outer {
        inners: vec![
            Inner { n: 1, factor: 2 },
            Inner { n: 2, factor: 2 },
            Inner { n: 3, factor: 3 },
            Inner { n: 4, factor: 3 },
        ],
        max: Max { v: 5 },
    });

    let mut s = mutex_s.lock().unwrap();
    
    s.inners.retain(|i| i.n * i.factor < s.max.v);

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Here I get the following error: `cannot borrow 's' as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable`.

I guess here I need interior mutability, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly, optimally and effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need concurrent access to `inners` and `max` you need them to be in different `Mutex`es, the `Mutex` should be [around the current type of `inners`, (in your example `max` is only accessed immutably so it doesn't need a `Mutex`) not around the whole `Outer` struct](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04efe5ede333f83cf7c582182b79a554). In other words: for *every* field that you need to access simultaneously you need a *different* `Mutex`, here that's just the `inners` member:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Outer {
    inners: Mutex<Vec<Inner>>,
    max: Max,
}

fn main() {
    let s = Outer {
        inners: Mutex::new(vec![
            Inner { n: 1, factor: 2 },
            Inner { n: 2, factor: 2 },
            Inner { n: 3, factor: 3 },
            Inner { n: 4, factor: 3 },
        ]),
        max: Max { v: 5 },
    };
    
    s.inners.lock().unwrap().retain(|i| i.n * i.factor < s.max.v);

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Alternatively, if the fields are visible to you (they are `pub` or `Outer` is a local type) you can split the borrow:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mutex_s = Mutex::new(Outer {
        inners: vec![
            Inner { n: 1, factor: 2 },
            Inner { n: 2, factor: 2 },
            Inner { n: 3, factor: 3 },
            Inner { n: 4, factor: 3 },
        ],
        max: Max { v: 5 },
    });

    let mut s = mutex_s.lock().unwrap();

    // splitting the borrow into `inners` and `max` so only `max` is captured in the closure.
    let Outer { inners, max } = &mut *s;

    // or for more control over the mutability:
    let Outer {
        ref mut inners,
        ref max,
    } = *s;

    inners.retain(|i| i.n * i.factor < max.v);

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Comment: The example that I provided is only an illustration of the real code. I didn't show the real code because it's too large. I put mutex in the right spot, I can't just move it because I share a variable that is similar to `Outer` across threads

Comment: I don't see how that would prevent you from sharing a `Outer` that contains `Mutex`es instead of sharing a `Mutex` that contains `Outer`. Neither does it preclude the second option I provide.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm looking for! I didn't see the answer edit. Thank you! Is' it possible to have `inners` as mutable reference and `max` as an immutable one? Here a both is mutable

Comment: You can reassign it `let max = &*max;` but the compiler is able to [coerce](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) it if you pass it to a function that expects a shared reference. See also my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

In case the optimal split-borrow in the other answer is not applicable to the real situation, an alternative would be the [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html)/use/reassign sequence.
It only costs a pointer swap.

```rust
    let mut inners = std::mem::take(&mut s.inners);
    inners.retain(|i| i.n * i.factor < s.max.v);
    s.inners = inners;
```

Comment: It's an interesting point  Thanks

Comment: There is a better solution; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is simple:

```rust
let s = &mut *mutex_s.lock().unwrap();
```

The explanation is a little longer.

Usually, the borrow checker allows us to *split borrows*: that is, have two mutable references to different fields of the same object. So why doesn't this code work?

It's because `s` is not a mutable reference, it's a [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html). `MutexGuard` derefs to a reference, but this step is inserted every time it's accessed. So `s.inners.retain(|i| i.n * i.factor < s.max.v);` is actually `(*s).inners.retain(|i| i.n * i.factor < (*s).max.v);`. The compiler cannot split the borrow before the `Deref`, since `Deref` can execute arbitrary code; and after it it's already too late.

The fix is simple: just deref eagerly, and make a mutable reference from the `MutexGuard`. This is what the `&mut *` does in the line of code above.